# Scroll List with Different ScrollBar

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components

I'm using the List and UIScrollBar components. I've got a list with a scrollbar placed far from it. I want to disable the built-in scrollbar in the list and scroll it with a different scrollbar. How is this possible?

Comment: Being able to change the width of the list's cells would do the trick as well. How can that be done if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the listBox MovieClip. Or you can make your own listBox.